# Android ViewPager custom TabIndicator not working

Tags: android, tabs

I have Googled around for a couple of hours now, for a solution on how to change the color of the TabIndicator in a ViewPager. From the documentation i get, that I should add a PagerTabStrip as the child to my ViewPager in XML. But this is not working as intended. Any suggestions on a solution?

Here is my code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.adrissa.klea.MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#934932"
    tools:context="com.adrissa.klea.MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.adrissa.klea.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this is what it looks like:
[image]

Obviously what I thought would be the end result is that the light blue tabIndicator was black, but it somehow gets underneath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the themes.xml file i added this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>
    </style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabs" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">

    <!-- tab indicator -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
</style>
```

Then this is the actionbar_tab_indicator.xml file in the drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- STATES WHEN BUTTON IS NOT PRESSED -->

<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />

<!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused" />


<!-- STATES WHEN BUTTON IS PRESSED -->

<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed" />

<!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed" />
</selector>
```

Then for the tab_selected state i create this xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="-6dp"
        android:left="-6dp"
        android:right="-6dp"
        android:bottom="0dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="#07368e"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then for my layout i get this tab indicator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to do this with these magic lines.

```
 PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
 pagerTabStrip.setDrawFullUnderline(true);
 pagerTabStrip.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.Black);
```

Comment: No the result is the same, the black color still appears as a full screen width box underneath the tabs.

Comment: remove background of <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip />
set background of viewpager

Comment: What do you mean by set background of viewpager? If you mean set the background as the id of the pagertabstrip, it's not working.

Comment: don't pass context to view pager

means remove this tools:context="com.adrissa.klea.MainActivity"

Comment: also give android:layout_gravity="top" to viewpager titlestrip

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pain in the ass, but it's still not changing anything.